# Capture a webpage table directly into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am fetching data from a url.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm"
driver.get(url)
```

I want to capture this table into df.

[image]

What is the best way to capture a web table directly into a dataframe?

Comment: Have you even tried it?  pandas is actually very good about importing tables from HTML.

Comment: This url is not getting fetched, have tried many times using pandas. tables = pd.read_html(url) . Would like to know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs in 4 seconds for me:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlyinglist.htm', headers=headers)
df = pd.read_html(response.content)
```

The table can be found under `df[0]`.